# SQL command to get only the recent input while Creating Database for messaging

Tags: mysql, database, wampserver

I have a created a database
[image: Pic of the database]

```
SELECT to_user_nick, message, sentat 
FROM user_messages 
WHERE send_user_nick = 'kb' 
ORDER BY sentat DESC
```

And I got the following output :

[image: Pic of the output]

The order is correct but what modifications or new line of code can I write that only the latest "message" from a "to_user_nick" should come as an output.

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

**EDITED**

> SELECT to_user_nick, message, sentat FROM user_messages WHERE send_user_nick = 'kb' ORDER BY sentat DESC LIMIT 1

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9bfd.jpg)

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user_messages WHERE send_user_nick = 'kb' ORDER BY sentat DESC

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Firstly, images of data aren't helpful to the volunteers here; we can't copy it, paste it, or interact with it. You've also tagged 2 RDBMS, MySQL and SQL Server, which are completely different products. Don't tag irrelevant products to your question. Please make sure you update your post and tag only the correct RDBMS for what you're using. Thanks

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score -1):

Adding TOP 1 will do the trick.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 to_user_nick, message, sentat 
FROM user_messages 
WHERE send_user_nick = 'kb' 
ORDER BY sentat DESC
```

but if you want to return the newly inserted record you can do check on `stored procedures`, `output` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, `@@IDENTITY`

Comment: its showing Error :

SQL query: Documentation
SELECT TOP 1 to_user_nick, message, sentat 
FROM user_messages 
WHERE send_user_nick = 'kb' 
ORDER BY sentat DESC LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 to_user_nick, message, sentat
FROM user_messages
WHERE send_user_nick = 'k' at line 1

Comment: is this sql or mysql?

Comment: try SELECT * FROM user_messages LIMIT 1.. because in sql my answer should work without any error.. not sure if it will work with mysql since they are different and your tag says sql

Comment: Doesn't this just display the latest message sent by KB and not what the OP wants (all the latest messages sent by kb to each individual other account)?

Comment: i'm using wamp server & the database is created in the localhost/phpmyadmin which is using MySQL

Comment: when you say "all latest messages" up to what date is the latest and/or how many messages should be displayed?

Comment: only the top most (ie recent message) from a particular user. "SELECT to_user_nick, message, sentat FROM user_messages WHERE send_user_nick = 'kb' ORDER BY sentat DESC LIMIT 1" i've posted the photo of this output in the question too

Comment: yes Magisch .. the LIMIT 1 clause is only showing 1 message sent by KB and not all the latest messages sent by kb to each individual other account..

Comment: yes i get it.. but until when is the recent.. till yesterday, last week or everything but to order it by latest?